# Split Cell On Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complicated split I need to do in VBA excel. I want to split each piece that starts "C:", includes "OCAK" and ends ".JPG" in range("C1") into A1,A2,A3... when click the button.

FROM THIS
[image]

TO THIS
[image]

I'm still doing research and testing, but I can't find a real viable solution. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub buton_Click()

If Cells(1, "c").Text Like "C:*OCAK*.jpg*" Then
   Dim jpgStart As Long
   jpgStart = InStr(Cells(1, "c").Text, ".jpg")
   Dim result As String
   result = Left(Cells(1, "c").Text, jpgStart - 1)
   Cells(1, "c").Offset(0, -2).Value = result
Else
   Cells(1, "c").Offset(0, -2).Value = vbNullString
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Like` or regex.

Comment: `Split` by `vbLf`, then `Split` by a space character. Then you can just test the `Left` and `Right` of your remaining string.

Comment: You could also do this with a formula, and a helper column. Do you need a VBA solution?

Comment: i couldn't do that, can you do that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the splitting actually. In the input, the new line should be used as a delimiter as well. Thus, consider changing the input a bit to something like this:

```
readCell = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "C")

readCell = Replace(readCell, Chr(13) & Chr(10), " ")
readCell = Replace(readCell, vbCrLf, " ")
readCell = Replace(readCell, vbNewLine, " ")
readCell = Replace(readCell, vbLf, " ")
```

Once the input is fixed an array can be built of the units - `myArray = Split(readCell)`. Looping through the array and using `Like "C:*OCAK*.jpg"` works quite well:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim readCell As String
    readCell = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "C")

    readCell = Replace(readCell, Chr(13) & Chr(10), " ")
    readCell = Replace(readCell, vbCrLf, " ")
    readCell = Replace(readCell, vbNewLine, " ")
    readCell = Replace(readCell, vbLf, " ")

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Split(readCell)

    Dim myVar As Variant
    Dim currentRow As Long: currentRow = 1

    For Each myVar In myArray
        If myVar Like "C:*OCAK*.jpg" Then
            Worksheets(1).Cells(currentRow, "A") = myVar
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot, is there a way doing this for a web page source code to get links

Comment: @emrey - you are welcome. Well, take a look at the [different scraping examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=vba%20scrape%20website). But in general, VBA is not the best scraping solution. Look for python and the beautiful soup library.

Answer (score 0):

In your button macro code loop the cells in column c; I have to assume you know how to set that up and do it. Then for each `cell` in that range:

```
with thisworkbook.worksheets("theNameOfYourSheet")
   dim loopRange As Range
   set loopRange=.Range(.Cells(1,3),.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count,3))
end with
dim cell as Range

for each cell in loopRange
    If cell.text Like "C:*.jpg*" Then
       Dim jpgStart As Long
       jpgStart = Instr(cell.text,".jpg")
       Dim result As String
       result= Left(cell.text,jpgStart-1)
       cell.offset(0,-1).Value=result
    Else
       cell.offset(0,-1).Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What didn't work? Can you be a bit more specific? Did the `Like` comparison not work or did the `result` not work?

Comment: both didn't work, when i click button it makes A1 = C:\ARALIK\4564131.pdf aralık ayı özet.
C:\OCAK\754321351351
Private Sub buton_Click()

If Cells(1, "c").Text Like "C:*.jpg*" Then
   Dim jpgStart As Long
   jpgStart = InStr(Cells(1, "c").Text, ".jpg")
   Dim result As String
   result = Left(Cells(1, "c").Text, jpgStart - 1)
   Cells(1, "c").Offset(0, -2).Value = result
Else
   Cells(1, "c").Offset(0, -2).Value = vbNullString
End If
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question above to add the current code you have. We need to see what you've done to try to sort out what's wrong.

Comment: It's clear my assumption that you know how to loop your range was incorrect. I'll make some changes. See my edited code.

Comment: The loop range consists of a single merged cell in the input. The input in this range is to be splitted and "fed" to the `Like` operator.

Comment: Merged cells are problematic. Can you do without them by using Center Across Selection format instead?

Answer (score 0):

- Split by `vbLf`
- Split by a blank space character
- Test against your result

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetOcak()

    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(Cells(1, 3).Value, vbLf)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    j = 1

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If Left(Split(arr(i), " ")(0), 7) = "C:\OCAK" And _
           Right(Split(arr(i), " ")(0), 4) = ".jpg" Then
            Cells(j, 1).Value = Split(arr(i), " ")(0)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```